# how to handle modal log-in using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, modal-dialog

I was trying to use python selenium to log in to a website. But the login is in a bootstrap modal dialog box, I cannot log in successfully using my code. Could someone please let me know what is wrong with my code?

I have tried the following code:

```
import requests
import time
import os, sys

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

gecko = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'geckodriver'))
binary = FirefoxBinary(r'C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, executable_path=gecko +'.exe')
driver.maximize_window() 
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10) 
time.sleep(1)

pageurl = "https://www.producemarketguide.com"
driver.get(pageurl)

popup = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="close-dialog"]')))
popup.click()

time.sleep(2)
login = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/header/div/div[2]/div[2]')))
login.click()

user = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/app-main/app-widget/screen-layout/main/current-screen/div/screen-login/p[3]')))
user.send_keys('xxx@gmail.com')

password = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/app-main/app-widget/screen-layout/main/current-screen/div/screen-login/p[4]/input')))
password.send_keys('XXXX')

submit = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/app-main/app-widget/screen-layout/main/current-screen/div/screen-login/p[6]/button')))
submit.click()
```

The error message I got is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                          
  File "pmg.py", line 34, in <module>                                                       
    user = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/app-main/app-widget/screen-layout/main/current-screen/div/screen-login/p[3]')))                             
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until                                                                              
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)                                     
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

That modal dialog is an iframe, so you need to switch to iframe to enter the credentials, try the below code:

```
accept_cookies = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler")
if accept_cookies.is_displayed():
    accept_cookies.click()
else:
    print("Accept Cookies button not displayed")

popup_dialog = driver.find_element(By.ID,"popup-dialog-window")
close_icon = driver.find_element(By.ID, "close-dialog")
if popup_dialog.is_displayed():
    close_icon.click()
else:
    print("Welcome dialog not displayed")

time.sleep(1)
# Clicking Login/Register link
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".user-login.user-login-front.pull-right #user-piano-login-register").click()
time.sleep(1)

# Switch to the login dialog iframe
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,".//iframe[starts-with(@id,'piano-id-')]"))

# enter the credentials and click Login button
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,".//input[@fieldloginemail]").send_keys("emailid")
time.sleep(0.5)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,".//input[@fieldloginpassword]").send_keys("password")
time.sleep(0.5)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,".//button[@actionlogin]").click()
```